# Twitter logging automatically by using the selenium module, Unable to locate element error

Tags: python, selenium

Hello i am trying to build a program that logins the twitter automaticaly by using the username and password informations with selenium module. I am getting an error which basically says it cannot find the element. This is the code i wrote

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

username=""
password=""


driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\geckodriver-v0.31.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")
usernameInput=driver.find_element(By.NAME,"text")
```

i also applied the same process by using xpath instead of name, it didin't work either. I am dropping a screenshot of where i got the name tag:
[image: SS]

Error message:

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
> locate element: [name="text"] Stacktrace:
> RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.jsm:12:1
> WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:192:5
> NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:404:5
> element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:291:16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a timing issue. Use `WebDriverWait` as shown below:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_experimental_option(
    "excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"],
)
prefs = {
    "credentials_enable_service": False,
    "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name="text"]'))
)
element.send_keys("MY_USERNAME")

time.sleep(3)  # Long enough to see the name was typed

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using this xpath:

`//span[text()='Phone, email address, or username']`

If this does not work,
Then use the above Xpath and just click the field and do not pass text.
Then in the next step, pass the value using:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[text()='Phone, email address, or username']").click()

usernameInput=driver.find_element(By.NAME,"text").send_keys(username)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i couldn't quite understand what you wanted me to do, i am new to all these stuff. It would be awesome if you showed it on a code. Sorry for bothering :/

Comment: Hey np. 
First check if this xpath is working or not:

```usernameInput=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[text()='Phone, email address, or username']").send_keys(username)```

If this does not work, then do this:

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[text()='Phone, email address, or username']").click()

driver.find_element(By.NAME,"text").send_keys(username)

Answer (score 0):

Should just be simple to send keys to that input tag.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@autocomplete='username']").send_keys('user')
```

Comment: I still have the same error :(